# issues with ibm_db in DB2 database with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I am using the ibm_db library. My development environment runs on windows.
Special characters appear in "�" accents.

When I make requests to the database the response looks like this:

[image]

```
{
    "COLNAME": "TELEFONO1",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Tel�fono",
    "ALIAS_CAMPO": "SVV.TELEFONO1"
}
```

When it should be:

```
{
    "COLNAME": "TELEFONO1",
    "DESCRIPCION": "Teléfono",
    "ALIAS_CAMPO": "SVV.TELEFONO1"
}
```

I have tried passing in the connection string DBCODEPAGE=1208 but it still doesn't work. I don't know what it could be.

```
let connStr = "DRIVER={IBM}; DBCODEPAGE=1208; DATABASE=" + process.env.DB_DATABASE + ";HOSTNAME=" + process.env.DB_HOSTNAME + ";PORT=" + process.env.DB_PORT + ";PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=" + process.env.DB_UID + ";PWD=" + process.env.DB_PWD + ";";
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Also note that [posts on Stack Overflow have to be in English](/help/non-english-questions). Do not add loose sentences in other languages. If you feel more comfortable asking in Spanish, feel free to try our sister site [es.so].

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a help desk! Please do not ask for help here.

Comment: Does your query return the same result using a SQL client where  `values 'Teléfono'` returns Teléfono ?

Comment: you have to set the DB2CODEPAGE environment variable externally to nodejs, i.e. in your windows operating system (you cannot "pass it in", cannot be in the connection string ), and it must be defined before the process that runs nodejs begins. (often easier to use a windows system environment variable for this purpose, and restart the process or reboot afterwards).

Comment: Whe I use a client, this query return "Teléfono". 
I think it has to do with the connector IBM, but I don't know where I should configure. Thanks por your help.